# using and/or for two equal things

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is preferred?

> The value of A or B is 50% each
>
> The value of A and B are 50% each
>
> The values of A and B are 50% each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single value:

The **value** of A and B is 50%.

and

The **value** of A or B is 50%.

The first sentence clearly means that both A and B have the value 50%.

The second sentence is ambiguous and needs additional phrasing to remove the ambiguity.

The value of A or B is 50%, but not both.

The value of at least one of A or B is 50%

I have avoided using **each** in all cases.

Comment: you said `The first sentence clearly means that both A and B have the value 50%.` In fact that is what I meant. A=50% and B=50%

Answer (score 1):

The third one is correct. The first is wrong because you wouldn't use 'each' with 'or'. The second is wrong because A and B are two things, so values needs to be plural.

Answer (score 1):

"The Values of A and B are 50% each."